# why car is not falling after joining mesh using rigibody in blender?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have problem animation. Why is the car not falling like the cube is falling? After I joined all parts of the car and using rigibody the car is not falling. The car is falling but its not like cube.
[image: gif of rigid bodies falling]

Comment: Hi, could  the plane somehow block the car...? or there is any other limit? try to show or describe the settings for all objects in the scene... 22MB of a sample file is a bit too much for me...

Comment: hi m. ardito..thanks for response.. i have solved my problem..there are some vertices need cleaned and scaled....problem solved